# Is there any elegance way to input boolean data in if statement

Tags: if-statement, coffeescript, boolean

I coded like below. 
item.count and item.chip 's data type is number

If item.amout is less than item.chip, completion variable is assigned to true.
If not, completion is assigned to false.
Then that variable is goes to value in hash.

But I think this is not a best way.

```
if item.amount is item.chip
    completion = true
    teamRegionModel.create
        isRegionCompleted : completion
else
    completion = false
    teamRegionModel.create
        isRegionCompleted : completion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of a JavaScript equality operator *is* a boolean value and CoffeeScript's `is` (or `==`) is just JavaScript's `===` in disguise. That means that this:

```
item.amount is item.chip
```

is a boolean expression and has the value `true` or `false`.

You don't need your `if`/`else` at all, you can simply say:

```
completion = item.amount is item.chip
teamRegionModel.create
    isRegionCompleted : completion
```

or, if you don't need `completion` elsewhere:

```
teamRegionModel.create
    isRegionCompleted : item.amount is item.chip
```

Comment: **@mu is too short** I tested this code. But when after I tested it, item.amout is item.chip didn't return boolean value. So I'll try it with Boolean function.

Comment: Should [work fine](http://coffeescript.org/#try:a%20%3D%201%0Ab%20%3D%202%0Ac%20%3D%201%0Ad%20%3D%20a%20is%20b%0Aconsole.log(d)%0Ae%20%3D%20a%20is%20c%0Aconsole.log(e)), what is the exact code that you're running?

Comment: Sorry. It's my mistake. I typed item.amount as item.amout.